# Excel how do I indicate in a cell if the value in another cell is used in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values, say in column k that I am using in formulas in another column.  For example based one or multiple values in column k, I will set a value in the other column.  I am trying to figure out which of the values in column k have already been used in the formulas.  Is there a way that I can indicate in column l (next to the value in k) whether that value has been used in a formula or not.  It would be exceptional if I could tell what cells in the formula column that value was used in (it could be in multiple), but that would be a nice to have, while the indicator whether or not it has been used is much more important.

Comment: We need more information.  A mock up with the formulas you are using and what you would like for an output would help a lot.  at first read this is not possible, but with more information we may be able to find something that may work.

Comment: The formulas are very simple.  I have a value in cell k2 through K30 (for example).  The values could by a Y or N, or could be a number.  Based on one or more of those values, I am setting another value, such as =if(k2="Y","Y","N") or if(OR(K2="Y",k16="N"),"Y","N").  Beside cell k2 (maybe l2), an indicator that K2 is used in a formula.  It could be a Y/N or any other value that would just provide an indication.  What I am trying to make sure is that all the values in k2 - k30 have been used in at least 1 formula.

Comment: you should provide a sample dataset with desired output